# What is the sum of the even (resp. odd) terms only of the Hockey-stick identity?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

The Hockey-stick identity is

$$\sum^n_{i=r}{i\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1} \qquad \text{ for } n,r\in\mathbb{N}, \quad n>r$$

I am trying to determine the values of the following

$$\sum_{\substack{i=r \\ i\,\text{even}}}^n{i\choose r}\;\text{and}\sum_{\substack{i=r \\ i\,\text{odd}}}^n{i\choose r}$$

EDIT WITH PARTIAL ANSWERS: The cases $r=0,1$ are clear, and I have been able to prove (i.e. beyond computer guesswork) that for $r=2,3,4$ and $n=2(k-1)$ the even sums are
$$\sum_{i=2}^{k}{2(i-1)\choose 2}={k\choose 2}+4{k\choose 3}$$
$$\sum_{i=3}^{k}{2(i-1)\choose 3}=4{k\choose 3}+8{k\choose 4}$$
$$\sum_{i=3}^{k}{2(i-1)\choose 4}={k\choose 3}+12{k\choose 4}+16{k\choose 5}$$
respectively. However, I am still at a loss regarding the general case.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha returns [a complicated expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum+of+binom+(2i,2r)+for+i+%3D+r..n) involving the generalized hypergeometric function, which tends to indicate that there's no better closed form than that. A typical approach to such questions would be to include $x^i$ in the sum and then add/subtract the results for $x=1$ and $x=-1$, but again, including $(-1)^i$ in the sum leads to [a complicated expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=sum+of+binom+(i,r)+(-1)%5Ei+for+i+%3D+r..n) involving the generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Do you really mean to start the sum $\sum\limits_{i=4}^k \dbinom{2(i-1)}{4}$ at $i=4$, and not earlier? Already for $i=3$ the binomial coefficient is nonzero, and to me it seems more natural to include it.

Comment: @darij-grinberg - Thank you yes, that was a typo I made when I typed the expression of the left.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to rewrite your sum as $a_{p,k} := \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \dbinom{2i}{p}$ for given $p$ and $k$. This is the number of all $\left(p+1\right)$-element subsets of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2k\right\}$ whose maximum element is odd. This doesn't seem to lead to an explicit form. But maybe we can explain why there are nonnegative integers $c_{p,p+1}, c_{p,p}, \ldots, c_{p,0}$ such that each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfies $a_{p,k} = c_{p,p+1} \dbinom{k}{p+1} + c_{p,p} \dbinom{k}{p} + \cdots + c_{p,0} \dbinom{k}{0}$.

Comment: Ah yes, we can explain this. Subdivide the set of all positive integers into the pairs $\left\{1,2\right\}, \left\{3,4\right\}, \left\{5,6\right\}, \ldots$. Then, if we want to choose a $\left(p+1\right)$-element subset $S$ of $\left\{1,2,\ldots,2k\right\}$ whose maximum element is odd, then we can proceed as follows: First choose how many of these pairs will have nonempty intersection with $S$; call this number $i$. Next, choose the specific $i$ pairs that will have nonempty intersection with $S$; there are $\dbinom{k}{i}$ choices here (since these pairs ...

Comment: ... must be among the $k$ pairs $\left\{1,2\right\}, \left\{3,4\right\}, \ldots, \left\{2k-1,2k\right\}$). Finally, choose $S$ by choosing at least one element from each of these $i$ pairs, totalling to $p+1$ elements, except that the largest pair must not get its even element chosen (because we want the maximum element of $S$ to be odd). The number of ways to do this latter step depends only on $i$, so we call it $c_{p,i}$, and is clearly nonnegative. Thus, $a_{p,k} = c_{p,p+1} \dbinom{k}{p+1} + c_{p,p} \dbinom{k}{p} + \cdots + c_{p,0} \dbinom{k}{0}$ holds.